# Update Recycleview in dialog

Tags: android, dialog, android-recyclerview

I have a the following dialog :

```
ChooserDialog = new MaterialDialog(this);
ChooserDialog.setView(linearLayout);
```

with a custom view (linearLayout)

In this LinearLayout i have a recyclerview that has onScrollListener for pagination. For a every new page a new ws request is made.

The problem is that when new results came form the recyclerview ( from the opened dialog ) is  not showing/adding the new results.

If i close and re-open the dialog every time new items came from ws .... it works

i think i need to redraw/update the dialog but i don't know how. Any help ?

Comment: This is virtually impossible to answer since you haven't really provided any code... How are you adding the items to the backing data set once they're loaded? Then, when/how/are you notifying the adapter of inserted items (that is, show some code illustrating `notifyItemRangeInserted()`, or - at a minimum - `notifyDataSetChanged()`)? Without any of that, it's pretty much guesswork.

Comment: Pleas post relevant code .

Answer (score 0):

I usually just set the adapter again with the new data

recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter)

Or if it's just a few elements, you can give them callbacks in the onBindViewHolder and update them individually.

Comment: if i put recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter) on every new recived items....it will refresh whit first position (top)

Answer (score 0):

Have you try to notify changes on the recyclerview adapter?

It should be something like this:
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();